# posting large data with php

Tags: php, post

I use `stream_context_create` and `fopen` to send data (POST method) with PHP.

The `$opts['http']['content']` works nicely but I now need to send a really big file (which couldn't be allocated in memory).

Is there a way to tell PHP that the `content` is a stream ?

e.g. `$opts['http']['content'] = fopen("/tmp/bigfile.bin");`

Does an other method (without curl) could be used to still use `stream_context_create` ?

Comment: As you probably know, `curl` can do it; not sure about whether stream contexts can. Why is curl not an option?

Comment: I've used stream everywhere in my project and would really prefer to stay like this if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fsockopen` instead.
Read the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

In this way you can use `fwrite` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) to send your data by chunks.

But you must write HTTP Headers manually to use it with web-server.